# UFW locks me out of server everytime I run it

Tags: 12.04, firewall, iptables, ufw, vps

Background: I'm setting up a new 12.04 instance on a VPS with a new provider.The VPS provider only offers a 32bit image but that really shouldn't matter here. I have no local access to the machine and there is no rescue system; every time I try something I have to use their web admin tools to reinstall the image.

Problem: Every time I try to install and setup UFW I end up being locked out of the server. Here are the commands I've been running:

```
 locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
 locale-gen "en_CA.UTF-8"
 apt-get update
 apt-get -y upgrade
 apt-get -y install nano ufw git
 ufw allow ssh
 ufw allow sftp
 ufw allow ftp
 ufw allow smtp
 ufw allow "Apache Full"
 ufw allow out 53
 ufw enable
```

I've also tried first running the defaults

```
 sudo ufw default deny incoming
 sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

As well as making sure that `-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` is in /lib/ufw/user.rules

In all cases and every combination I've tried I end up losing the connection to the server and being totally locked out. I've had to reinstall the image about 5 times now. This is my fourth Ubuntu 12.04 server but for some reason it's totally different than the others. All of the others are running UFW with no problems.  I also tried all of the above steps on a Debian 7 64bit image with this VPS provider but had the same problem.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that this is problem with my OpenVZ VPS; you cannot modify kernel files on a non KVM system like OpenVZ.

Your best bet is to forget about UFW entirely and write the iptable rules directly, or try this work around:

http://blog.kylemanna.com/linux/2013/04/26/ufw-vps/